# Null pointer in my Facade :(

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, facade

I've written a task manager, and well it;'s a long story... all in Java by the way. So I wrote a Facade which you can see below there is a problem with the HashMap and I suspect that the values which I attempt to add into the HashMap during the construction aren't going so well. The method that is triggering the null pointer exception is the create method. the input parameters to the method have been verified by me and my trusty debugger to be populated.

any help here would be great... I'm sure I forgot to mention something so I'll reply to comments asap as I need to get this thing done now.

```
package persistence;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.HashMap;

import persistence.framework.ComplexTaskRDBMapper;
import persistence.framework.IMapper;
import persistence.framework.RepeatingTaskRDBMapper;
import persistence.framework.SingleTaskRDBMapper;

public class PersistanceFacade {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static Class SingleTask;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static Class RepeatingTask;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static Class ComplexTask;

    private static PersistanceFacade uniqueInstance = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private HashMap<Class, IMapper> mappers;

    public PersistanceFacade() {
        mappers = new HashMap<Class, IMapper>();
        try {
            SingleTask = Class.forName("SingleTask");
            RepeatingTask = Class.forName("RepeatingTask");
            ComplexTask = Class.forName("ComplexTask");
            mappers.put(SingleTask, new SingleTaskRDBMapper());
            mappers.put(RepeatingTask, new RepeatingTaskRDBMapper());
            mappers.put(ComplexTask, new ComplexTaskRDBMapper());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}

    }

    public static synchronized PersistanceFacade getUniqueInstance() {
        if (uniqueInstance == null) {
            uniqueInstance = new PersistanceFacade();
            return uniqueInstance;
        }
        else return uniqueInstance;
    }

    public void create(UUID oid, Object obj) {
        IMapper mapper = (IMapper) mappers.get(obj.getClass());
        mapper.create(oid, obj);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object read(UUID oid, Class type) {
        IMapper mapper = (IMapper) mappers.get(type);
        return mapper.read(oid);
    }

    public void update(UUID oid, Object obj) {
        IMapper mapper = (IMapper) mappers.get(obj.getClass());
        mapper.update(oid, obj);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void destroy(UUID oid, Class type) {
        IMapper mapper = (IMapper) mappers.get(type);
        mapper.destroy(oid);
    }


}
```

Comment: Where do you define mappers in the create() method in mappers.get(obj.getClass());?

Comment: What happens when you run this in a debugger? This should help you get an understand of what is happening.

Comment: I see now that mappers gets initialized in the constructor. How are you invoking create()?

Comment: create is invoked from elsewhere... but what seems most important is that in the debugger the mapper in the mapper.get call is null

Comment: Are you calling create with an instance of SingleTask or a sub-type? If it's a sub-type then they will have different classes and so the hashes will be different?

Comment: do you mean mappers.get or mapper.create call?

Comment: Please debug the application (or add a System.out.println) and check what the 'obj.getClass()' call returns in the returns method.

Comment: @Jim SingleTask is a conrete class, sub-type of Task which is a sub-type of SubjectAbstact which is a sub-type of PersistenceObject which provides the commit method which then leads to the create being called based on the objects state

Comment: @Jim the sys.out said: "class domain.objects.RepeatingTask"    which is a valid type.

Comment: Can you also add the stacktrace of NPE?

Comment: Please also do sys.out on mappers and see if RepeatingTask is in there

Comment: @CoolBeans sorry but i have no clue how to get a stack trace in eclipse..

Comment: @rodion mapper.toString() returns {}... I think we have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your problem lies in the constructor:

```
    try {
        SingleTask = Class.forName("SingleTask");
        RepeatingTask = Class.forName("RepeatingTask");
        ComplexTask = Class.forName("ComplexTask");
        mappers.put(SingleTask, new SingleTaskRDBMapper());
        mappers.put(RepeatingTask, new RepeatingTaskRDBMapper());
        mappers.put(ComplexTask, new ComplexTaskRDBMapper());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
```

You silently ignore the `ClassNotFOundException`. If you add logging to the catch I expect it to tell you that the class `SingleTask` is not found, as I expect that you did not put those classes in the default package.

Given your reply to comments these classes are in the `domain.` package, so you could try to change to:

```
    try {
        SingleTask = Class.forName("domain.SingleTask");
        RepeatingTask = Class.forName("domain.RepeatingTask");
        ComplexTask = Class.forName("domain.ComplexTask");
        mappers.put(SingleTask, new SingleTaskRDBMapper());
        mappers.put(RepeatingTask, new RepeatingTaskRDBMapper());
        mappers.put(ComplexTask, new ComplexTaskRDBMapper());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log.warn("Cannot load class", e);
    }
```

Btw, adding logging to your code will help to find the reasons behind unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

For `Class.forName("RepeatingTask")` to return a class you must have a class `persistence.RepeatingTask`. But in your comment you say that `obj.getClass()` returns `domain.RepeatingTask` so it looks to me like you have 2 "RepeatingTask" classes or `domain.RepeatingTask` is a sub type.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName("SingleTask");` is throwing a ClassCastException, so mappers does not get populated. Since you are ignoring `ClassCastExeption` in your constructor you have missed that error, it seems.